# Do USB emulators exist for Linux?

Tags: virtualbox, usb-drive, virtualization

I'm looking for software that lets me have many virtual USB drives on my Ubuntu installation. I want them to be seen by virtual machines in VirtualBox so I can do backup operations. I need the drives to be presented on USB bus and not as virtual hard disks.

Comment: Have you seen  [this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10872883/1182783)?

Comment: well his solution is very hard to be understand :S

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly? You want to simulate many usb hard disk to your virtual machines to test backup programs.

Comment: @jofel yep , but not hard disk ! flash . Mass storage

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion: Switch to `qemu/qemu-kvm`. It can simulate usb mass storage devices to virtual machines. See [here](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/usb2.txt) for some examples.

Comment: I can't change virtual box . it's used by my company

Comment: can i use them both ?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/usb-vhci/index.php?title=Build_and_install_the_linux_kernel_modules

Comment: I found this but couldn't install it

Comment: You need to install the kernel headers to compile it.